# Allocating enormous array on heap; program doesn't crash and compiles without error

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, ram

I was messing around in Code::Blocks, and tried to create a massive integer array on the heap. I was astonished to find that the code compiled, and even ran without crashing. Thinking this was just GCC/Code::Blocks, I tried it in Visual C++ too. Surprisingly, it compiled and ran fine too with Visual Studio.  I checked in Task Manager, and the process wasn't even using up much RAM. Why is this allowed, and how does an array like this even get allocated?

```
int main() {

    int* arr = new int[1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024];

}
```

Code::Blocks gives me the following warning:

> *warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]*

If it warns me about this, why doesn't the compiler try to stop me from creating the array?

Comment: Print out the actual value that the expression evaluates to. If it overflows, it will likely wrap around the maximum value to a smaller value.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It evaluated to 0, which makes a lot of sense why it works. I'd suggest adding an answer to the question, since this solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating that big of an array. Your number is overflowing and wrapping around to something much smaller.

Do this:

```
size_t sz = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
cout << sz << endl;
int * arr = new int [sz];
```

and see what happens.

That being said, your program is valid. Therefore, the compiler should compile it and generate code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to users *Colonel Thirty Two* and *yzt*, the expression evaluated to 0 because of an integer overflow when it was printed out. This caused an array of size `0` to be created, creating no compiler/run-time errors.